# Why is the monitored Kafka consumer lag value not always correct?

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring, lag, consumer, exporter

I am running Apache Kafka on **Kubernetes** using **minikube** and I have also a Pod with a **confluent consumer** written in python. I am monitoring Kafka broker metrics with a **JMX exporter** and consumer metrics with **kminion consumer exporter**. These exporters are also 2 seperate pods. Lastly I have **Prometheus** monitoring both of these exporters and reading the metrics.

I am producing 2 messages per second to a certain topic. My consumer consumes a message and then runs a task. The task needs 0.4 seconds to complete. So I am also consuming with a rate of 2 messages per second.

My hypothesis is that the queue lag metric should be either zero or 2 at all times since I am producing and consuming at the same rate. I am monitoring the queue every second and this is what I get over a period of 5 seconds:

```
t = 0: Queue is 0.
t = 1: Queue is 3.
t = 2: Queue is 5.
t = 3: Queue is 7.
t = 4: Queue is 9.
t = 5: Queue is 0.
```

And it repeats the same cycle. So the avg_over_time of the queue lag is 5. Why is this happening? I know the consumer cannot consume 9 messages at once since it runs a task that takes 0.3 seconds to complete and therefore my maximum consume rate is 2 perSecond.

I have also tried using a different exporter for consumer metrics but I still get the same results.

Comment: What kind of consumer it is? Is it Streams? What's your partition assignment strategy?

Comment: I was using confluent Kafka consumer and my partition assignment was set to auto. Disabling auto commit and offset commiting after every task execution seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When is your consumer committing the offsets?

If you are not manually committing offsets after processing each message, by default, a consumer commits them every 5 seconds: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_auto.commit.interval.ms

Which would explain why you see these queue values

Comment: Yep I had enable.auto.commit enabled so it was auto commiting every 5 seconds. I have set auto.commit to false, auto.commit.interval.ms to 1 second and calling consumer.commit() after I run my task and that seemed to work thanks so much!